# C type casting: bitwise or arithmetic

Tags: c

I was wondering how type casting works in practice between types (in "embedded" C). For example: if I have a `Signed 16-bit` number with value `-80d`, `11010000b`, and i want to cast it into `unsigned 16-bit`. which value do i get, would it be just 80d, or would it be 208.

what i mean is, is the conversion bitwise or arithmic? does just the interpretation of the bits change, or does the conversion really change the bits?

if it does really change the bits, how would i have to do it in such a way just the interpretation changes.This would be done for example when i read a u8 value from an i2c device and have to interpret the bits as a signed value.

Lastly, actually the same as above: if it does not change the bits, how would i cast it so it changes the bits and not the values?

Kind regards,
Jesse

Comment: This is defined precisely in the C standard [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3)

Comment: -80 isn't `11010000`, it's `11111111 11010000`. There are 16 bits and the number is [sign extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you make a cast, you trigger a type conversion, which is specified by C11 6.3.1.3:

> **6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.60)
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

The procedure of converting from signed to unsigned is covered by the second paragraph. It is written in this weird way to cover all manner of signedness formats. What it means in practice on a 16 bit two's complement system, is that from `-80d` (hex `FFB0h`) you end up with the value `FFB0h`, which is the unsigned number `65456d`.

It doesn't change any bits.

Comment: Again, it doesn't change any bits on *2's complement system*, not that the others would be really relevant.

Comment: i.e. the result would always be `0xFFB0`, be it 2's or 1's or sign+magnitude system, but the bits would naturally change in 1's or sign+magnitude system.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Same for all signedness formats actually, since the new type is unsigned, after which signedness does not apply. -80 + 65536 gives 65456 no matter signedness format. The bits will not change, because an unsigned 16 has the same representation on all allowed systems.

Comment: Yeah I mean that in 2's complement the signed presentation has the same bits set as well

Comment: @Lundin but -80 has a different representation to 65456 in signed magnitude or one's complement. So sure the result will always be 0xFFB0 but the original bit pattern is different (in each case) to get that result. I.e. the bit pattern will change except in 2's complement.

Comment: Since the OP obviously has a 2's complement system, this whole discussion is not very relevant. In addition, derailing the topic into a discussion about rare and exotic signedness formats is not going to help any beginner (if any person at all), but just make them more confused.

Comment: @Lundin sure, but your comment above implies that the bit representation of -80 and 65456 is the same for all signedness formats. That could confuse people. Your answer OTOH is fine IMO.

Comment: @Lundin: I might not disagree that discussing one’s complement may burden beginners, but I believe it is important to take care that are statements are true. The statement “It doesn’t change any bits” is not strictly true. While perhaps we should not burden beginners with exotic information, neither should we lay misconceptions in their minds.